# How to integrate HAPI FHIR JPA server into existing project

Tags: spring-boot, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm new to HAPI FHIR and looking to integrate the HAPI FHIR JPA server into my existing project. Any quick tips or resources you can share?

I'm looking to store FHIR resources in a database and utilize the HAPI FHIR JPA server for my project. Any advice or best practices on setting up and configuring the HAPI FHIR JPA server would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

I have visited hapi-fhir documentation page also try to understand this git hub repo but https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter , but there is no particular steps to integrate hapi fhir jpa server into existing spring boot project.